# Symfony 3.4 - Make sure annotations are installed and enabled

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to implement a forgot password feature to an existing Symfony app. So fare I have the password request done. The user puts in it's email and an email is sent with a token. The return URL looks like this:

/intranet/password-change/f74eab6dca8b5ed6fd46e7893221254b655f94799589e0b83c

Normally a forme should show but when i visite that URL i get this message:

> Class App\Controller\ResettingController does not exist in
> /public_html/intranet/src/AppBundle/Controller/ (which is
> being imported from "/public_html/intranet/app/config/routing.yml").
> Make sure annotations are installed and enabled.

I don't get it ... I have the controller set up at the right place and the route should be taken care of by the annotations.

My routing file:

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation

coop_tilleuls_forgot_password.reset:
    path:   '/api/forgot-password'
    defaults:  { _controller:  coop_tilleuls_forgot_password.controller.forgot_password:resetPasswordAction}
    methods:  [POST]

coop_tilleuls_forgot_password.update:
    path:   '/api/reset-password/{tokenValue}'
    defaults:  { _controller: coop_tilleuls_forgot_password.controller.forgot_password:updatePasswordAction}
```

as for my resseting class it's in
/public_html/intranet/src/AppBundle/Controller

And looks like this:

```
<?php 
// src/Controller/ResettingController.php
namespace App\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Email;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\TokenGenerator\TokenGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormErrorIterator;
use App\Entity\User;
use App\Services\Mailer;
use App\Form\ResettingType;
/**
 * @Route("/password-change")
 */
class ResettingController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/{id}/{token}", name="resetting")
     */
    public function resetting(User $user, $token, Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
    {
        // interdit l'accès à la page si:
        // le token associé au membre est null
        // le token enregistré en base et le token présent dans l'url ne sont pas égaux
        // le token date de plus de 10 minutes
        if ($user->getToken() === null || $token !== $user->getToken() || !$this->isRequestInTime($user->getPasswordRequestedAt()))
        {
            throw new AccessDeniedHttpException();
        }
        $form = $this->createForm(ResettingType::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
        {
            $password = $passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user, $user->getPlainPassword());
            $user->setPassword($password);
            // réinitialisation du token à null pour qu'il ne soit plus réutilisable
            $user->setToken(null);
            $user->setPasswordRequestedAt(null);
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();
            $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('success', "Votre mot de passe a été modifié.");
            return $this->redirectToRoute('security_login_form');
        } 
        return $this->render('security/resetting.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
        
    }
}
```

I am new to symfony so I might be missing something obvious ... I just don't see it lol thx in advance

Comment: App vs AppBundle - One or the other but not both.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you elaberate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JUst replace App by AppBundle

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;
```